# Reference Error With Local Files In Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build

I am having issues, it would seem, with using local files with my phonegap application. I am trying get a simple app up and running to scan a qr code and just display the text that was scanned. However, it is not working for some reason. I can run any JavaScript I want as long as it is in the index.html file. For some reason, whenever I try to call a function from an included js file, I get a reference error. In this code I am getting 'ReferenceError: scan_qr_code is not defined' and 'ReferenceError: onDeviceReady is not defined'. Both of these functions are from the main.js file which is supposed to be included from the index.html file. I downloaded and inspected the apk file and these files are being included in the build but for some reason are not working. Anyone have any suggestions or advice? This is driving me nuts. Seems like this should be a rather straight forward thing. Also, I'm building with the PhoneGap version as 3.7.0

I am using PhoneGap build for compiling and my folder structure is setup as thus.

```
/www
  /scripts
    main.js
    jquery-1.11.3.min.js
  /styles
    main.css
  index.html
  config.xml
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="childbrowser.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/barcode.js"></script>

<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<title> </title>

<script>
$(function(){
    alert('here');
     try{
        $("#scan_button").click(function(){
            alert('Button Clicked 2');
            try{
                onDeviceReady();
                scan_qr_code();
            }catch(e){
                alert(e);
            }
        });
    }catch(e){
        alert(e);
    }
});

document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
     try{
        $("#scan_button").click(function(){
            alert('Button Clicked');
            try{
                scan_qr_code();
            }catch(e){
                alert(e);
            }
        });
        scan_qr_code();
    }catch(e){
        alert(e);
    }
}, false);
</script>

</head>
<body>

<button id="scan_button">Scan QR Code</button>

</body>
</html>
```

### main.js

```
$(function(){
});

function onDeviceReady(){
   alert('Device Ready Fired');
}

function scan_qr_code(){
    try{    
        alert('Scanning');
        // Scan the QR code
        barcode_app.scan(function(result){
            code = result.text;
            // Just grab the text from the scanned code
            alert(code);
            scan_qr_code(){
        });
    }catch(e){
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

### config.xml

```
<preference name="phonegap-version"            value="3.7.0" />
<access origin="*"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be a very wild guess, but it look like your main.js file has an extra `{` that shouldn't be there.

```
scan_qr_code(){
```

This could be breaking your code, and that's why your functions from main.js are undefined.

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UgtaSEuVevcD2pv7Eu2p?p=preview) showing that the code would run just fine if you remove the extra `{`. Well... `barcode_app` is now showing as undefined, I assume it's part of the `scripts/barcode.js` file, which by the way, is not included in your project structure either.

Comment: That was it. I was trying to loop itself with another call to the `scan_qr_code()` function and had a `{` instead of a `;`. Corrected the issue and now it's working. Thanks!